# IndependentTag - How do i call this in Revit?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have a working Ribbon Tab with panels and buttons which work in calling Dialog boxes just for testing. I am now attempting to call this bit of code from Autodesk's site, which should create a new IndependentTag, however it is not working.

```
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
public class Tagtest : IExternalCommand
{
    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///       The CreateIndependentTag
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="document">The <see cref="Document" /></param>
    /// <param name="wall">The <see cref="Wall" /></param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="IndependentTag" /></returns>
    public IndependentTag CreateIndependentTag(Document document, Wall wall)
    {
        TaskDialog.Show("Create Independent Tag Method", "Start Of Method Dialog");
        // make sure active view is not a 3D view
        var view = document.ActiveView;

        // define tag mode and tag orientation for new tag
        var tagMode = TagMode.TM_ADDBY_CATEGORY;
        var tagorn = TagOrientation.Horizontal;

        // Add the tag to the middle of the wall
        var wallLoc = wall.Location as LocationCurve;
        var wallStart = wallLoc.Curve.GetEndPoint(0);
        var wallEnd = wallLoc.Curve.GetEndPoint(1);
        var wallMid = wallLoc.Curve.Evaluate(0.5, true);
        var wallRef = new Reference(wall);

        var newTag = IndependentTag.Create(document, view.Id, wallRef, true, tagMode, tagorn, wallMid);
        if (null == newTag) throw new Exception("Create IndependentTag Failed.");

        // newTag.TagText is read-only, so we change the Type Mark type parameter to 
        // set the tag text.  The label parameter for the tag family determines
        // what type parameter is used for the tag text.

        var type = wall.WallType;

        var foundParameter = type.LookupParameter("Type Mark");
        var result = foundParameter.Set("Hello");

        // set leader mode free
        // otherwise leader end point move with elbow point

        newTag.LeaderEndCondition = LeaderEndCondition.Free;
        var elbowPnt = wallMid + new XYZ(5.0, 5.0, 0.0);
        newTag.LeaderElbow = elbowPnt;
        var headerPnt = wallMid + new XYZ(10.0, 10.0, 0.0);
        newTag.TagHeadPosition = headerPnt;

        TaskDialog.Show("Create Independent Tag Method", "End Of Method Dialog");

        return newTag;
    }

    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the CreateIndependentTag method from the Execute method.
The Execute method is what is actually called by Revit, and currently yours is only throwing an exception.

Additionally, the CreateIndependentTag method expects a wall, as well as the document as parameters. The document can be obtained from ExternalCommandData.
The wall can either be obtained by prompting the user to select a wall, or by taking a pre-selected wall. In this case, we will prompt the user to select the wall and validate the selection afterwards.

Finally, you need to wrap the call to CreateIndependentTag in a Transaction, as you are making changes to the document.

Putting it all together looks like this:

```
public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        UIDocument uidoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
        Document doc = uidoc.Document;

        Reference reference;
        try
        {
            reference = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element, "Pick a wall");
        }
        catch
        {
            return Result.Cancelled;
        }

        var element = doc.GetElement(reference);

        if (element == null || !(element is Wall wall))
        {
            TaskDialog.Show("Error", "Selected element was not a wall");
            return Result.Failed;
        }

        using (Transaction trans = new Transaction(doc, "Creating tag"))
        {
            trans.Start();

            CreateIndependentTag(doc, wall);

            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
```

A few notes: it would be preferable to create an implementation of ISelectionFilter to restrict the user's selection to only walls. I also like to check the existing selected object first using `uidoc.Selection.GetElementIds()` to see if a wall is already selected before prompting the user to select one.  The Building Coder blog should have lots of examples related to these 2 points.

Comment: Good grief! Granted i was just starting this developer journey but looking at my question from a year ago is embarrrasing! :)